# Reverse proxy to another machine

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, proxy, reverse-proxy

**Explanation of what I am trying to do:**

I have 2 servers on the ip 192.168.1.10 (docker reverse proxy) and 192.168.1.20 (other services). I want 10 to redirect requests to 20 (many of these requests are with SSL).

**Example:**

| user request |  | answer back |  | return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example_internal.host.com | → | 192.168.1.10 | → | https://example_internal.host.com |
| example_external.host.com | → | 192.168.1.20 | → | https://example_external.host.com |

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm:0.6.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=example_external.host.com
    networks:
      - frontend

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:stable
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=example@email.com
    networks:
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

  nginx_internal:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    hostname: example_internal.host.com
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example_internal.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example_internal.host.com
      - NGINX_HOST=example_internal.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=example@email.com
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - letsencrypt
    networks:
      - frontend


  nginx_external:
    hostname: example.host.com
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./scm-proxy
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example_external.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example_external.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=example@email.com
      - ENABLE_NGINX_REMOTEIP=1
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - letsencrypt
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
   frontend:
     driver: bridge
```

**scm-proxy/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**scm-proxy/nginx.conf:**

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass        http://localhost:80;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

(In several places I have read that I must put in "/etc/hosts" the resolution of the dns, which would be something like "192.168.1.20 example_external.host.com")

The truth is that this is my first time using this technology and I have not been able to find much information and what I have found has been quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is the configuration that has worked for me:

## Comments:

Some details are missing such as the `nginx.conf` file automatically taking the `example_external.host.com` in the `server_name` field, but it will be later.

On the other hand, you have to be careful with `DEFAULT_HOST=` if it is declared, **you may get errors**. I recommend commenting on it until it works and then uncommenting it

I recommend using this command: `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans --build`

## Files:

### docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm:0.6.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy
#    environment:
#      - DEFAULT_HOST=example_internal.host.com
    networks:
      - frontend

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:stable
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=example@email.com
    networks:
      - frontend

  nginx_external1:
    container_name: tests
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./scm-proxy
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example_external.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example_external.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=example@email.com
    extra_hosts:
      - "example_external.host.com:192.168.1.20"
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - letsencrypt
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
   frontend:
     driver: bridge
```

### scm-proxy/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

### scm-proxy/nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example_external.host.com;
#
    location / {
#        proxy_pass         http://example.com;
#        proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.20;
        proxy_pass         http://example_external.host.com;
    }
  }
}
```

A special thanks to [@richardsefton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3105020/richardsefton) for his dedication

Answer (score 1):

the nginx config there is reverse proxying to itself on port 80. If you want to reverse proxy to one of the other containers change lacalhost to whatever service name you gave the container. eg `http://nginx_external:80`

If that does not work, try ammending your config to being something along the lines of:

```
upstream app {
    server app:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name <your_host_here>;
    return 301 https://<your_host_here>$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name <your_host_here>;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     
        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection          'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_buffer_size       128k;
        proxy_buffers           4                   256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}
```

The above is tried and tested in my own dev container stack

Comment: I have to try this. I have a question, could I pass "nginx_external" as a variable somehow?  The idea would be to be able to reuse that same file for different Hosts.  I would also be interested in redirecting other services, not just the http.  Can I achieve that?

Comment: On that I don't have an answer I'm afraid

Comment: I've tried it and can't get it to work. At all times it returns "502 Bad Gateway"

Comment: Try removing proxy_redirect entirely

Comment: It doesn't work either. I'm really starting to think that I can't do it for some external reason

Comment: let me dig out my nginx config that i know works proxying from an nginx container to a node container running an express server.

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. Using "docker logs" gives me this:  `/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration`  
`/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/`  
`/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh`  `/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh`  
`/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh`  
`/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up`

Comment: Hello [@Richardsefton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3105020/richardsefton) ,I wanted to vote positively for your work, but my lack of reputation prevents it, so I will have to settle for thanking you in writing. Greetings and thank you!