# Connection refused when trying to access a Docker container from another Container in Azure Pipeline with curl

Tags: docker, azure-devops, connection

I have two Docker containers. Container A is connected to a postgresql database and Container B is a client which should put data into the database with "curl" through port 9292 of A. This is the command which I'm running with subprocess() from a python script in B:

```
broker_addr = "pactbroker"
broker_port = "9292"     
command = "curl -v -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u 'pact_broker:pact_broker' -d@repo/consumer-provider.json http://" + broker_addr + ":" + broker_port + "/pacts/provider/Provider/consumer/Consumer/version/1.0.0"
                subprocess.run('exec bash -c "' + command + '"', shell=True)
```

I've set up both containers locally and this worked perfectly. However when I'm trying to do the same in an Azure Devops Pipeline I get the following error message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to pactbroker port 9292: Connection refused
```

I tried to use the --network flag for both containers but this didn't change anything. These are the commands with which I tried to build Container A. The name should be correct, it runs on TCP port 9292 and I also exposed the port:

```
run --network pactnet --name pactbroker -p 9292:9292 --expose 9292 --expose 1234 --expose 5432 --env PGPASSWORD="password" -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=pact_broker -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=pact_broker -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=hostname -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=pact_broker -d img_pactbroker
```

Here is the same command as docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  pactbroker:
    image: img_pactbroker
    container_name: pactbroker
    expose:
      - 9292
    ports:
      - 9292:9292
    environment:
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST: "hostname"
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME: "pact_broker"
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME: "pact_broker"
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "pact_broker"
      PGPASSWORD: "password"
      
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: pactnet
    
volumes:
  postgres-volume:
```

My first guess was that it might have something to do with the proxy so I added the proxy flag to my python command:

```
command = "curl --proxy http://proxyaddress:8080 -v -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u 'pact_broker:pact_broker' -d@repo/consumer-provider.json http://" + broker_addr + ":" + broker_port + "/pacts/provider/Provider/consumer/Consumer/version/1.0.0"
```

This resulted in a Bad Gateway Error. From my understanding, the command tried to push the data to the proxy now:

```
> Authorization: Basic cGFjdF9icm9rZXI6cGFjdF9icm9rZXI=
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 2513
> 

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: squid/3.5.27
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 13:25:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 3835
< X-Squid-Error: ERR_ZERO_SIZE_OBJECT 0
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Content-Language: en
< X-Cache: MISS from proxyserver02
< X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxyserver02:8080
< Via: 1.1 proxyserver02 (squid/3.5.27)
< Connection: keep-alive
```

I also tried to reset the proxy environment when building the container but this didn't help either.

```
--env http_proxy="" --env https_proxy=""
```

This is the Dockerfile with which I build the image for Container A:

```
FROM pactfoundation/pact-broker:latest

ENV VSTSUSER 1003

ENV GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR $HOME
USER root

RUN apk update && apk add
RUN apk upgrade

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies build-base

RUN apk update && apk add bash
RUN apk add postgresql
RUN apk add ruby
```

I don't know what could cause this connection problem. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using docker-composer, reading individual lines is painful to look at.

Two, using "network" does not make machine (machine = container) A know that machine B is picking up requests with the name "app" (or any other name).
I leave an example of how to ask the question with [docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367524/7292043). It is also likely that you are missing the "extra_hosts" tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your hint with docker-composer. I'm actually relatively new to Docker so this kind of advice is always helpful. About your answer: Adding a host didn't solve the problem. I'm thinking that the problem isn't caused by the host itself because it seems to recognize the host. curl could resolve the host, it just can't connect to the port.

Comment: As indicated above, it is very likely that you need the `extra_hosts` tag (it edits the **"/etc/hosts"** file). That a container knows how to resolve a host is not a guarantee of anything, it only indicates that at some point it was able to resolve it. On the other hand, you could connect a local one with an external one and it worked for you? As I also told you, you can edit the question and form it with docker-compose, it will be nice for everyone.

Comment: @TheEater If in your question you speak of a container A and a container B the logical thing would be that in your docker-compose both appear